# Give Id to every looped button and set on click listener based on button's id

Tags: java, android, sqlite, button

I have a program that will retrieve some data from database, and show it on the screen as some buttons. How can I give an Id to every button created and make button.OnClickListener to every button with the correct id?

Here is my codes :

```
private void selectAllGroup() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
MyGroup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvListGroup);
Database allGroup = new Database(MyGroupActivity.this);
allGroup.open();
listGroup = allGroup.countHowManyGroups(username);
layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LLMyGroup);

String groupName[] = allGroup.fetchGroupName(username);

for (int i = 0; i < listGroup; i++) {
    newBt = new Button(this);
    newBt.setText(groupName[i]);
    layout.addView(newBt);
}

allGroup.close();
}
```

And here is my database code (if needed) :

```
public int countHowManyGroups(String username) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String Query = "SELECT " + GROUP_NAME + " From " + MS_GROUP
            + " a INNER JOIN " + MS_GROUP_DETAIL + " b ON a." + GROUP_ID
            + "=b." + GROUP_ID + " WHERE " + MEMBER_USERNAME + "=?";

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(Query, new String[] { username });
    int cnt = c.getCount();
    c.close();
    return cnt;

}

public String[] fetchGroupName(String username){
    int i=0;

    String Query = "SELECT " + GROUP_NAME + " From " + MS_GROUP
            + " a INNER JOIN " + MS_GROUP_DETAIL + " b ON a." + GROUP_ID
            + "=b." + GROUP_ID + " WHERE " + MEMBER_USERNAME + "=?";
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(Query, new String[] { username });
    String groupName[] = new String [c.getCount()];
    int iGroupName = c.getColumnIndex(GROUP_NAME);

    c.moveToFirst();
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        groupName[i] = c.getString(iGroupName);
        i++;
    }

    c.close();
    return groupName;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to your question "How can I give an Id to every button created and make button.OnClickListener to every button with the correct id?"

Simply use inside your for-loop:

```
newBt.setId(id to set) // Should be positive, doesn't have to be unique
newBt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //The View carries the Id
                v.getId();
                //Then you can simply set up a fast Switch-case for example
                switch (v.getid()) {
                case 1:
                       break;
                default:
                       break;
            }
        });
```

**Update**

No Problem just cast Button to the View in the onClick-Method and get the String:

```
newBt.setId(id to set) // Should be positive, doesn't have to be unique
newBt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Button myClickedButton = (Button) v;
                String buttonText = myClickedButton.getText();

                //Do something with your logic here. 
                //You can also Switch-case on a String ! But AFAIK 
                //it's only possible on Java Compiler 1.7 or above. 
                //But Eclipse will guide you if you want to Switch on String
        });
```

Comment: @piyush regarding to piyush answere: And how should he know which button was clicked if he doesn't want to fo the same logic for every button?..

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer,, What if I want to get the buttontext from the clicked button? can it pass through?

Answer (score 0):

You can setTag for each button inside the for loop as

```
    newBt.setTag(i);
    newBt.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and inside your OnClick method get the tag as the position like

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        int buttonClicked = (int) view.getTag();
        // Do your code here according to the position of the button clicked
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < listGroup; i++) {
    newBt = new Button(this);
    newBt.setText(groupName[i]);
   newBt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //write your logic to do the work you need when button is clicked.You do not need id for this.
            }
        });
    layout.addView(newBt);
}
```

You don't need id for listening to button click event.